# Should I transpile my node js code for using ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8

I am using nodejs only for server side microservices, I want to use ES6, I have read that Babel is used to transpile code to ES5 to provide support for browsers. So I need to know if I am not writing this code for client side would I still need to transpile it to run it on V8 engine? Or is it just an extra layer which won't be needed on server side?

Comment: No using ES7 is probably the way to go. Why would you  speak spanish with your neighbour if both can speak english natively?

Comment: If you're using ES modules (which are ES6), you still need to transpile. Also, the thing you're calling 'ES6' may contain features that are naturally transpiled by Babel but aren't supported by Node/V8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server works on the new versions of Node.js and it supports ES6 features, you don't need to transpile your code. Your code only works in the same place, if it is hosted in one place.

Transpiler is used, when your code is written in newer versions, there may be users which use browsers with old versions of Javascript. So the browser need to get the JS code from the hosted place and run locally, here may be errors. In this case you need to use transpiler.

Comment: So if I am using nodejs purely for server side code I do not need to transpile it I would only need it if it is served on client side right? Something like an Angular js code to provide an UI.

Comment: Yes, you catch it.  Simple JS code and client side frameworks must be transpiled (if they don't by default), because they work for each user. Each user runs it in his/her browser

Comment: Why are you talking about browsers getting the JS code? The question makes it clear they aren't.

Comment: I describe the case which he asked in the comment. Add give an answer mostly in which cases he can/need to use transpiler

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a transpiler if your runtime doesn't support the language features you are using.

The *latest* version of Node.js has [**almost** complete support for ES6](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

If you use features unsupported by whatever version of Node.js you are using, you will need to use a transpiler.

Comment: To summarize: everything except tail calls.

Comment: Yes but I can see there are not much features that are unsupported and I believe using ES5 for those features in server side microservices would be more feasible instead of having a transpiler. What do you suggest?

Comment: @TGW — "but"? That's what I said! I'm not going to tell you how much benefit you will get from using those features vs how much effort you'll save by not using a transpiler. That's a judgement call only you can make,.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the code as a microservice, you don't need to do transpiling. All latest versions of Node.js support es6 by default. You can refer here for more information of what es6 features are currently supported by Node

[Node.js es6 documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest ues es6/es7 directly in the latest nodejs. 
Now the latest nodejs almost support most functions except import/export.

If so, you can use arrow function, async await etc.. which can make your code more clear.